# Get the AMI ID of an AMI created with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm building an EC2 instance with Ansible, then creating an AMI from the instance. I'm sure I'm missing something here, but how do I get the DI of the newly created AMI? I've tried:

```
tasks:
- name: create an ami in us-east-1
  ec2_ami: wait=yes
           aws_access_key={{ ec2_access_key }}
           aws_secret_key={{ ec2_secret_key }}
           instance_id={{ item }}
           region={{ region1 }}
           name=data-mgmt-qa-006
  with_items: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_instance_id']
  register: ec2_ami_info

- debug: var=item
  with_items: ec2_ami_info.image_id
```

and:

```
tasks:
- name: create an ami in us-east-1
  ec2_ami: wait=yes
           aws_access_key={{ ec2_access_key }}
           aws_secret_key={{ ec2_secret_key }}
           instance_id={{ item }}
           region={{ region1 }}
           name=data-mgmt-qa-006
  with_items: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_instance_id']
  register: instance

- debug: var=item
  with_items: instance.image_id
```

The latter 'register' is copied from the docs, but I'm not able to get the right with_items obviously.

The AMI is being created fine. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ran debug var=instance, and got:

```
TASK: [debug var=instance] **************************************************** 
ok: [54.90.128.104] => {
"instance": {
    "changed": true, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "changed": true, 
            "image_id": "ami-be14b9d6", 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "wait=yes aws_access_key=**** aws_secret_key=**** instance_id=i-393284d2 region=us-east-1 name=blah", 
                "module_name": "ec2_ami"
            }, 
            "item": "i-393284d2", 
            "msg": "AMI creation operation complete", 
            "state": "available"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Given that:

```
- debug: var=instance.results[0].image_id
```

gave the correct results.

Answer (score 2):

The `ec2_ami` task is correct, but your invocation of the `debug` module is wrong. Try this:

```
- debug: var=instance.image_id
```

or alternatively

```
- debug: msg={{instance.image_id}}
```

You don't need `with_items` here since there's only one value. `with_items` is a loop.

Comment: Thanks Ben. (Sorry for the formatting.) This returns: 
TASK: [debug var=instance.image_id] ******************************************* 
ok: [54.198.217.217] => {
    "instance.image_id": "{{ instance.image_id }}"
}

or:

TASK: [debug msg={{instance.image_id}}] *************************************** 
fatal: [54.166.30.127] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'image_id'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting